# Awk: write in newline every two fields

Tags: shell, awk

I have my doc with differents lines size :

```
TITLE
NAME VALUE foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
NAME VALUE foo2 bar2 foo2 bar2
NAME VALUE foo3 bar3
```

I want to delete the title and delete the two firsts fields, then print newline every two fields like this :

```
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo2 bar2
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

My output is actually :

```
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
foo2 bar2 foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

With this code :

```
awk -F' ' 'NR>1, NF>2 {
s = ""; for(i = 3; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s
}' file_input.txt > file_output.txt
```

I don't found solution.
If someone can help me.
First time on stack overflow !
Thank you

Comment: `NF>2` suggests there may be lines with just 2 fields that are to be ignored; if this is true, please update the question with an example line of input where `NF==2`

Comment: all of the sample inputs have an even number of fields; if an input can have an odd number of fields, how should this be handled when inserting `\n` characters? should the last line contain 3 fields? or should the last line contain 1 field? again, please update the question with a sample input line with an odd number of fields (also update the expected output)

Comment: @markp-fuso I want to ignore always the 2 firsts fields of each line.

And is not possible to get odd number of fields, it's why I wanted to explain with my exemple in input

Comment: @shellter it was a mistake ! I edited my post thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```
awk 'NR>1{ for(i=3; i<=NF; i=i+2){ print $i,$(i+1) } }' file
```

Output:

```
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo2 bar2
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `gnu awk` with [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) having a pattern matching 2 fields that are delimited by 1 or more whitespace characters.

As the title is a single field:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\S+\\s+\\S+' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

Output

```
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo2 bar2
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

Or starting from the second line:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\S+\\s+\\S+' 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

Comment: you made me discover the FPAT option.
thanks for this alternative

Answer (score 1):

`sed` alternative, won't win in readability compared to `awk`.

```
$ sed -E '1d;s/\w+ \w+ //;s/( \w+) /\1\n/g' file

foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo2 bar2
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

Comment: Perhaps a slight tweak? `sed -nE 's/(\S+ \S+) //;s//\1\n/pg' file`

Comment: right! `\S` is probably the right shorthand.

Comment: It works with @potong tweak ! thanks